# Deploying IIS Settings with Web Deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, deployment, virtual-directory, webdeploy

If I look at the Package/Publish Settings of a web application in Visual Studio 2010, there is an option to "Include all IIS settings as configured in IIS Manager (used only for IIS Web projects)"

I am using IIS instead of the VS Dev Server to run my web application, but when I deploy the package that Web Deploy creates to a remote server, the IIS settings that get applied to my remote IIS application are at the least, unfamiliar, and at the worst, completely wrong.

For instance, my local IIS has 2 virtual directories (images, sounds). But when I deploy, it creates 4 completely different virtual directories (_controltemplates, _layouts, _vti_bin, _wpresources), and if I manually create the 2 correct vdirs on the remote server beforehand, Web Deploy will delete them. Where the heck did Web Deploy get those from? Web Deploy also mis-applied the correct authentication settings on the remote IIS application.

Since the "Include all IIS settings as configured in IIS Manager" setting doesn't seem to pick up the right settings, I ultimately want to be able to create some kind of configuration file that Web Deploy will use as part of its deploy package. Ideally something that I can check into source control. But I can't figure out from the documentation how to do this. I see something about parameterization and manifests, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd465323.aspx

Comment: Ever work this out? Seems the same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895802/how-do-i-specify-an-iis-website-to-create-a-deployment-package-via-visual-studio

Comment: unfortunately, no. it was easier for me at the time to deploy the changes manually than try to ensure they were all correctly specified in the deployment package. If you figure it out, please post an answer, I'd love to know!

Comment: check this option: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28v=ws.10%29.aspx run command that will create required directories

Answer (score 1):

Here is another article to look at. See the note about IIS Configuration, not all settings will be inherited, check if Windows authentication is set to true on the default web site.

Package/Publish Web Tab, Project Properties
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410108.aspx